# DNA - methylation profiles of tumors based on TCGA datasets

Tags: r

I have tried to analyse DNA - methylation profiles using raw data of tumors from TCGA datasets  using minfi or limma R packages but the samples were not provided by a sample sheet. Do you know a way how to easily import iDAT files from TCGA with minfi or limma or how I could get the corresponding sample sheet required?

I tried have downloaded the IDAT files with the TCGAbiolinks package:

```
query_methyl <- GDCquery(project = 'TCGA-BLCA',
                          data.category = 'DNA Methylation',
                          data.type = 'Masked Intensities',
                          access = 'open',
                          experimental.strategy = 'Methylation Array',
                          platform = 'Illumina Human Methylation 450',
                          file.type = 'idat', 
                          sample.type = c('Primary Tumor', 'Solid Tissue Normal'))
```

but from there I can not import the idat files into R as the sample sheet is missing.
Do you have any ideas?